# CURL: Code 0 from proxy after CONNECT?

Tags: php, proxy, curl

I am trying to test the below function but every time I try to use any sort of proxy IP (I have tried about **15** now) - I generally get the same error:

```
Received HTTP code 0 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Here is the function, anything wrong with it? It could just be the proxies I am using but I have tried several times now.

```
function getPage($proxy, $url, $referer, $agent, $header, $timeout) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

    $result['EXE'] = curl_exec($ch);
    $result['INF'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $result['ERR'] = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

Also in general, anyway I can improve it?

I appreciate all help.

### Update

As I submitted this, I tried another proxy and it worked!

The other question still stands, how can I improve the above. It takes about 3-4 seconds to execute, anything I can do, or is this too minimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you sort of answered your first problem but code `0` is not a valid http status code. They should all begin with either 1 (informational),  2 (success), 3 (redirection), 4 (client error), or 5 (server error). I would be really interseted if anyone knows why you might get this code. Searching the [libcurl site](http://curl.haxx.se/) didn't bring anything up.

(More detailed information is here if you are interested:
[http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.htmlt](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html))

---

For the second question I think you would need to find where the longest operation was.The `microtime()` function might be useful to you here. The [documentation for microtime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) has some example scripts to help you use the timer.

I suspect though that most of the 3-4 seconds could be waiting to get the response via the proxy at `curl_exe($ch)`.