# git push -u origin master error: Received HTTP code 0

Tags: github

I used this command several times and it worked every time but today after I created a repo and use it again an error occurred:

```
git push -u origin master
```

it gave me this:

```
error: Received HTTP code 0 from proxy after CONNECT while accessing https://github.com/[myrepo]

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I used `echo $http_proxy`  and got `http://127.0.0.1:48100` .But I don't remember I ever set this.(I do use this one for my firefox sometimes.) And I used the `unset` command but it still gave me the same error. Is there a way I can set this proxy thing to none permanently?

Is there some other ways to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you consider:

- the question "[CURL: Code 0 from proxy after CONNECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943265/curl-code-0-from-proxy-after-connect)"
- the error code (which isn't a valid [http error code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html))

it seems your current `http_proxy`/`https_proxy` environment variables (or your `git config --global http(s).proxy`) don't reference a valid proxy anymore.
Check also the syntax used for those proxys (each one should begin with `http://...` as in `http://host:port`).